# is 6-benzylhexanoic acid the same as 7-phenylheptanoic acid?

Tags: nomenclature

is 6-benzylhexanoic acid the same as 7-phenylheptanoic acid? If the two compounds stated are equal, what's the more preferred IUPAC name?

Comment: Draw their structure for yourself and you will know, if they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

The two molecules below are the same, with just an alternative naming:

$$\ce{(Ph-)-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-COOH}$$

$$\ce{(Ph-CH2-{})-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-CH2-COOH}$$

The former is preferred, as the benzyl substituent does not have sense to be used, if attached to the last carbon of the main chain.